# Are these parts really LEGO?

Tags: part-identification, clone-brands

[image: mystery pieces next to a LEGO brick]

Hello, can anyone tell me if these yellow and red items are real LEGO parts? I have a sneaky feeling that they have made it into the LEGO pile via somebody 'selling LEGO bulk' but I don't want to throw them out if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Those look like the Playmobil clip-on necklace pieces. Playmobil doesn't have the same level of part listing that LEGO does, but I was able to find [this picture](https://thumbs.ebaystatic.com/images/g/cT8AAOSw5cNYSjdT/s-l225.jpg) of the yellow one being worn.

[image: pic of yellow part]

Comment: And now that picture is broken. Disappointing.